# Table Entry Comparison Against Static Array in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table of multiple rows and columns which contains Sign-in events by username. Each row provides other details such as Time, IP Address, Device info, Location info, etc. I have another table which is a single row with multiple columns of IPv4 Ranges (a watchlist). These IPv4 Ranges are considered "malicious". I would like to be able to return data from the SigninLogs table and compare the IP Address element of each row against each IPv4 Range to verify if the IP Address is a member of any IP Range found in the "malicious" table. If this condition is true, I wish to perform specific action. The function to perform a "range" analysis on an IPv4 subnet is

```
ipv4_is_in_range(<IP Address>, <IP Range>)
```

I have tried a few different methods, all of which have gotten nowhere. Here is an example of a strategy I have tried:

```
let GetPackage = (v_IPAddress: string){
    _GetWatchlist('Bad_IP_Ranges')
    | summarize IPAddresses = make_list(pack_array(IPAddress))
    | mv-apply IPAddresses on ( 
        where ipv4_is_in_range(v_IPAddress, tostring(IPAddresses))
    )
};
SigninLogs
| union AADNonInteractiveUserSignInLogs
| extend Malicious_IP = iff(GetPackage(IPAddress), IPAddress, "null")
| project TimeGenerated, Category, ResultType, ResultDescription, Identity, Malicious_IP, AppDisplayName
| order by TimeGenerated | take 1000
```

This gives an error:

```
iff(): argument #1 must be a scalar expression
```

I understand that it's complaining about the GetPackage() function returning a tabular value, but I do not know how to force the GetPackage() function to return just the malicious IP Address if the where statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of new methods that should be helpful here (note that they are only available if you are using EngineV3):

1. [has_any_ipv4_prefix()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-any-ipv4-prefix-function)
2. [has_any_ipv4()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-any-ipv4-function)

Comment: I don't think either of those functions will check for a whole range. For example, if I have the range 157.78.44.0/24 in my list of Malicious IP Ranges and I have an IP 157.78.44.102 as an entry in my SigninLogs, then I want to be able to check that IP against the entire list of ranges in the Malicious IP Ranges array. So, because 157.78.44.102 is in the subnet of 157.78.44.0/24, that would be true and that row of SigninLogs would be projected because it matches a malicious IP range

Comment: 157.78.44.0/24 range expands to list of Ips from 157.78.44.1 through 157.78.44.254.
Therefore has_any_ipv4_prefix(msg, ‘157.78.44.’) can be used for matching. Did you try these functions on your Kusto cluster? If so please provide a specific example and we will look into it.

Comment: The prefix function does not always work, either. If the subnet mask is above /24 in which less than 1 class C range is covered, the prefix function cannot be applied. For example, say we have the range 157.78.44.128/25 and the IP 157.78.44.102. The IP would not be a member of the subnet above, yet if I use the prefix function has_any_ipv4_prefix(msg, '157.78.44.'), the IP would match.

Answer (score 0):

### Use lookup function in scalar context:

```
let lookup = toscalar(GetPackage
        | summarize l=make_list(vpn_ip_cidr));
    SigninLogs
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
    | mv-apply l=lookup to typeof(string) on
        (
        where ipv4_is_match (IPAddress, l)
        )
    | project-away l
```